# how to display only first 10 characters of file name that they upload in the html page

Tags: javascript

The code to print the file name is

```
<div id="file">'+filename+'</div>
```

i want only the first 10 characters of the file name and not the all. what java script function can i use as i cannot use php.

Comment: Why can you not use PHP ? how is this output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you wanted the code for getting the DIV contents as well. 
Complete example below:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="file">I want the first 10 characters</div> 

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var div = $('#file');
        var str = div.text();
        var stripped = str .substr(0, 10);

        alert(stripped);
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "this is isdfisdf";
console.log(str.substr(0, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first 10 characters from a string in JavaScript use [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```
var str = str.substr(0,10);
```

or using [`substr()` in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) :

```
$str = substr(str,0,10);
```